# Prove that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

Tags: group-theory

Let $µ: G × S → S$ be a left action of the group $G$ on the set $S$. Define a relation $\sim$ on $S$ by: $s \sim t ⇔ $ there exists $g∈G$ such that $µ(g, s) = t$.

Need to prove that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

(HINT. Show that
a) $\sim$ is reflexive i.e. $s\sim s$ for all $s∈S$;
b) $\sim$ is symmetric i.e. if $s\sim t$, then $t\sim s$ for all $s,t∈S$;
c) $\sim$ is transitive i.e. if $s\sim t$ and $t\sim u$, then $s\sim u$ for all $s,t,u∈S$.)

Comment: Nice hint, it gives the definition of an equivalence relation.

Comment: Please show whatever work you have done on this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

What's $\mu(1,s)$? What's $\mu(g^{-1},t)$ if $\mu(g,s)=t$? What about $\mu(gh,s)$?

Comment: I am pretty "green" in this matter... It would be great if someone could solve this exercise :)

Comment: @DovilėGaučytė It's just applying the definitions, really.

Comment: And how to apply?

Comment: @DovilėGaučytė You're unlucky: I got to see the previous version of your comment. Bye.

Comment: Well, I was honest at least :)) Is it too hard for you to solve this exercise for me if you know how? I would really appreciate it..

Comment: @DovilėGaučytė No, it's quite easy for me. The information is available; use the definitions.